Boot without assembling RAIDs or starting Volume Groups
I'm trying to create a generic rescue system. It works well except that it assembles any RAIDs it finds and starts any volume groups. Depending on my situation, I may not want that in a recovery situation. So, how do I:

Configure a system to not assemble any RAIDs? (I have "raid=noautodetect" on the kernel command line, but they still assemble).
Prevent volume groups from starting at boot.

